# JQuery : Assign null to selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns. I want the second dropdown, `Assign` value to be set to null when the specific value which is `student` from the first dropdown is chosen.

First dropdown:

```
<select name="Reg">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>
```

This is the second dropdown which is hidden, shown only when `Reg` with value `admin` is chosen.

```
<select name="Assign"> 
  <option value="">Choose</option> 

<?php
$sql=odbc_exec($conn,'SELECT AssignCd, AssignNm FROM AssignList');
if(odbc_fetch_row($sql))
  {
    $AssignCd= odbc_result($sql, "AssignCd");
    $AssignNm= odbc_result($sql, "AssignNm");
    echo "<option value='".$AssignCd."'>".$AssignNm."</option>";
  } 
?>

</select>
```

I tried by doing the following but it doesn't work.

Please Help.

```
if($("#Reg").val("student");) {
  $("#AssignCd").val(""); 
  $("#AssignNm").val("");
}
```

**UPDATED:**

When `Admin` is selected, `Assign` with `admin is chosen` will be automatically selected. The problem is when I change my option to `Student`, the supposed value `student is chosen` is not shown.

How can I make the `Assign` value of both `Admin` and `Student` stay as it is and not jumbled up between them?

This is my code :

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mxnnn/b8103m7j/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Reg").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() === 'Admin') {
       $("#Assign").show();
    $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="student_assign"]').attr("disabled",true).prop("selected", false).wrap('<span>');
    $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="admin_assign"]').prop('selected',true);
  }
  else if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() === 'Student') {
     $("#Assign").show();
  $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="student_assign"]').prop('selected',true);  
  } else {
  $("#Assign").hide().attr("disabled"," ");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="Reg" id="Reg">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<select name="Assign" id="Assign"> 
  <option value=" ">Choose</option> 
  <option name ="student_assign" value="student_assign">student is chosen</option>  
  <option name ="admin_assign" value="admin_assign">admin is chosen</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: what element is `#AssignCd` and `#AssignNm` ?

Comment: Change `name="Reg"` to `id="Reg"` or just add it, Or you can change `$("#Reg")` to `$('select[name="Reg"]')`

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't work @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: They are the PHP variable that needed to be pass to the DB @guradio I need the values to be set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$('select[name="Reg"]').on('change', function() {})` this will trigger when you select an option in your `select`
- `$(this).find("option:selected").val() == "student"` this will see if you have select an `option` with value "student"
- `$('select[name="Assign"] option[value="AssignCd"]').text("");` this sets the text of the `option` with value = AssignCd to empty

This is how far we can go without showing us your generated html for `<select name="Assign">`

```js
$('select[name="Reg"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "student") {
    $('select[name="Assign"] option[value="AssignCd"]').text("");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Reg">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<select name="Assign"> 
  <option value="AssignCd">AssignNm</option>
  
</select>
```

**Update**

There is no need to use `.wrap()` as far as i can see, use `.hide() / .show()` look at the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Reg").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() === 'Admin') {
      $("#Assign").show();
      $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="student_assign"]').attr("disabled", true).prop("selected", false).hide();
      $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="admin_assign"]').prop('selected', true);
    } else if ($(this).find("option:selected").text() === 'Student') {
      $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="student_assign"]').attr("disabled", false).prop("selected", true).show()
      $('select[name="Assign"] option[name="student_assign"]').prop('selected', true);
    } else {
      $("#Assign").hide().attr("disabled", " ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="Reg" id="Reg">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<select name="Assign" id="Assign"> 
  <option value=" ">Choose</option> 
  <option name ="student_assign" value="student_assign">student is chosen</option>  
  <option name ="admin_assign" value="admin_assign">admin is chosen</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find the solution based on your answer. If you don't mind, could you see my updated question? I encountered some problems. @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I get it. Thank you. They work perfectly now :) @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Reg" id="Reg">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>
```

First of all `#<selector>` is used to select Dom elements which have an id `<selector>`. You cannot access them with the name attribute and id selector.

As for your issue. you need to use the `on change` event of the first drop down to decide the visibility of the second drop down.

```
<select name="Assign" id="Assign">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  ....
  ....
```

```
$('#Assign').hide(); // first hide it so they cannot see it
$(document).on('change', '#Reg', function(e){
    if($(this).val()=='admin'){
        $('#Assign').show();
    }else{
        $('#Assign').val('').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer I managed to find my own solution. If you don't mind could you help me with my updated question? @Bhadra